# How To Make a Video Playlist In Html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to make a a slider video playlist like [this one](http://ensemblevideo.com/demo/videoslider.aspx). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO! For your information, this isn't exactly a how-to website. We only try to help with specific programming questions. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Hi @MartyMcVry 
I've tried this code http://support.ensemblevideo.com/video-slider-widget/

But I dont Know How to insert images in the playlist.
when i try to view my page in my browser the playlist shows default images provided by ensemble and also they ask for money to edit playlist.
thats why I want my own playlist pls help me with the coding.